# What kind of connector is this (similar to Molex)?

Tags: identification, connector

I would like to replace the cable attached to this connector but it seems to have some kind of special locking mechanism on the top.

It has 12 poles with a standard spacing between the pins of 2.54 mm and looks Molex-like but does not seem to belong to the usual suspects.

[image: Connector, all dimensions in mm]

How can identify this connector and purchase a suitable replacement?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=keyed+pin+header&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=,+Mini-PV+Female+Connector+Housing,+2.54mm+Pitch,+12+Way,+2+Row&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=APq-WBvuZhVFhUgGwOHAiAC_aC3KUd4CXw:1644457514928&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGwJnQgfT1AhUEjYkEHVFMAsIQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1020&bih=682&dpr=1

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75: Thank you, that is exactly the one. Do you want to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: _Molex-like_ Well, as it turns our, it _is_ a Molex connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an industry standard connector, an "unshrouded rectangular connector, female housing, with polarizing key". The one you drew is made by Molex ([P/N SL 70450](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0022552122/313630).

[image: Molex SL 70450] {Credit: Digikey}

Amphenol ICC makes a similar one (the polarizing key is slightly different) (P/N [69176-012LF](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-icc-fci/69176-012LF/1002698)).